# Jquery validate submit handler not working With Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, validation

I am trying to submit the form using jquery validate and ajax.But it doesnt work.neither it throws any error.

here is the html

```
{% if form %}
            <form method="POST" action="." id="change_password_form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="{% trans 'change password' %}"/>
            </form>
        {% else %}
            <p>{% trans 'Your password is now changed.' %}</p>
        {% endif %}
```

Here is the script

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
        $("#change_password_form").validate({
            rules: {
                password1: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength:10

                },
                password2: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength:10
                },
            },

            messages: {
                password1: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                },
                password2: {
                    required: "Please Confirm your password",
                },
            },

            submitHandler: function(form) {

                var pass = $('input[name=password1]').val();
                var repass = $('input[name=password2]').val();

                if (pass != repass) {
                    console.log("error")
                }
                else {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: $(form).attr('method'),
                            url: $(form).attr('action'),
                            data: $(form).serialize(),
                        })
                        .done(function (response) {
                            $('#loading-image').hide();
                            if (response.location == 'accounts/password/reset/key/done/'){
                                window.location = "{% url 'home' %}"
                        }

                        }).error(function(response){
                            console.log(response)

                        });
            return false;
           }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Somehow the submit event is not occurring ? what can i do to submit the form using ajax and jquery validate

Comment: can i show your complete solution: html+javascript ?

Comment: Inside your `submitHandler` you should actually submit the form. Next to the validate() method you can then listen for the forms submission `$(form).on('submit', function() { //do ajax submit }`  and do the ajax submit.

Comment: updated the question@Amani

Comment: Can you post your solution please@TheF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some minor changes in your code, i think you had a typo.

The problem was you was using the rules without "" and jquery.validate was not able to recognize.

I also added a custom validation to control if the passwords are the same, all validations should be with standard rules or customs but you shouldn't add validations into submitHandler method.

```
 $("#change_password_form").validate({
        rules: {
            "password1": {
                required: true,
                maxlength:10,
                "isSamePassword": true
            },
            "password2": {
                required: true,
                maxlength:10,
                "isSamePassword": true
            }
        },

        messages: {
            "password1": {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                maxlength:"Max 10",
                isSamePassword: "Pwd no son iguales"
            },
            "password2": {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                maxlength:"Max 10",
                isSamePassword: "Pwd no son iguales"
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {

            $.ajax({
                   type: $(form).attr('method'),
                   url: $(form).attr('action'),
                   data: $(form).serialize(),
               })
               .done(function (response) {
                   $('#loading-image').hide();
                   if (response.location == 'accounts/password/reset/key/done/'){
                       window.location = "{% url 'home' %}"
               }

               }).error(function(response){
                   console.log(response)

               });
           }
    });
    $.validator.addMethod("isSamePassword", function(value) {
        var pass = $('input[name=password1]').val();
        var repass = $('input[name=password2]').val();
        return pass === repass;
    }, 'Pwd no son iguales');
```

Comment: equalto element giving me unnecessary "Please enter the same value again." every time i hit the input box

Comment: and the request still not going through

Comment: @AdityaSingh please add the Id's into the input fields

Comment: i cant add ids as form is becoming from behind

Comment: @AdityaSingh then i am afraid we cant use the equalTo functionality and you will have to add your validation manually or add a customRule as you wish...

Comment: @AdityaSingh I modified the response, now i created a new customRule to check the passwords values and dont modify the html code